# Show piecewise function is integrable and find the definite integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, riemann-integration

The question is:

Show from the definition of Riemann integrability that $g:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by $$g(x)= \begin{cases} 
      1 & x \in \{\frac{1}{10},\frac{2}{10},...,\frac{9}{10}\} \\
      0 & otherwise
   \end{cases} $$

is integrable on $[0,1]$ and find $\int_{0}^{1}f(x) dx$.

I started off by saying:

For each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, let D be the dissection $0 < \frac{1}{10}-\frac{1}{n} < \frac{1}{10}+\frac{1}{n}<...<\frac{9}{10}-\frac{1}{n}<\frac{9}{10}+\frac{1}{n}<1$ such that we choose $n$ large enough so that the intervals $[\frac{i}{10}-\frac{1}{n},\frac{i}{10}+\frac{1}{n}]$ are disjoint.

How would I then evaluate the lower and upper sums? I think the lower sum would be equal to $0$ since even though the interval length is $\frac{2}{n}$, the infimum of the function is equal to $0$, but the upper sum seems a bit more complicated.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, each lower sum is $0$. And the upper sum that corresponds to your partition is $\frac{18}n$. Since $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{18}n=0$…

Comment: Thanks for your reply! May I ask how you got to the upper sum equalling $\frac{9}{n}$?

Comment: Of course. On each interval $\left[\frac k{10}-\frac1n,\frac k{10}+\frac1n\right]$, $\sup f=1$; on any other interval of the partition, $\sup f$ is $0$. So, the upper sum is the sum of the lengths of $9$ intervals with length eqaul to $\frac2n$. Therefore, it is $\frac{18}n$. (I wrote $\frac9n$ in my answer, but that was a typo.)

Comment: Ah okay, thank you! Just to check, if for any other interval of the partition i.e. $[\frac{k}{10}+\frac{1}{n}, \frac{k+1}{10}-\frac{1}{n}]$, the sup$f=\frac{1}{2}$ rather than $0$, how would you then calculate the upper sum incorporating the different supremums from different intervals?

Comment: The upper sum would be half the sum of the lengths of those intervals that you mentioned plus $\frac{18}n$.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach you may use with the Riemann Integralbility. The constant function $h(x)=0$ is Riemann integrable in $[0,1]$ and $\int_{0}^{1}h=0$ . Now if you change the value of $h$ at finite number of points like $\{\frac{1}{10},\frac{2}{10},...,\frac{9}{10}\} $ you get again the same integral....